# What is meant by interval of positive length?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

For example if $I=(1,3)$ Then $\text{length}(I)=3-1=2$. Right?
So all interval have positive lengths? How can it be negative? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No intervals have negative length, but some can have $0$ length.

For example $[1,1] = \{1\}$ is a interval of $0$ length. It is degenerate and contains only one point.

Comment: U mean intervals don't have negative lenghts?

Comment: @Fahim Yes. Intervals such as $[4,-4]$ consists of no point, so their length is $0$.

Comment: Got it. All intervals have nonnegative lengths!! Thank u Henry